# SQL Between Dates where ending can be null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a SQL statement where I am looking start date and end date is between the range. The one problem I am running into is it the end as not been update and is null. I am trying to add the current date into that field in the example

> If I do this I should see the last two rows I dont see any row at this time.

```
(CAST(StartDate AS Date) >= '2019-08-22') AND ((CAST(EndDate AS Date) <= '2019-08-22') or (EndDate IS NULL))
```

Table data

```
    StartDate               EndDate
    2017-07-18 14:40:00.000 2017-10-13 16:29:09.723
    2017-10-13 16:29:09.723 2017-10-27 10:36:55.990
    2017-10-27 10:36:55.990 2017-12-12 15:01:51.600
    2017-12-12 15:01:51.600 2018-01-24 15:08:53.637
    2018-01-24 15:08:53.637 2018-04-04 10:56:27.110
    2018-04-04 10:56:27.110 2018-05-25 14:14:13.863
    2018-05-25 14:14:13.863 2018-05-25 14:41:16.033
    2018-05-25 14:41:16.033 2018-10-17 15:45:58.517
    2018-10-17 15:45:58.517 2018-12-18 11:33:37.663
    2018-12-18 11:33:37.663 2019-02-11 11:22:52.053
    2019-02-11 11:22:52.053 2019-08-21 10:40:17.937
    2019-08-21 10:40:17.937 2019-08-21 10:40:25.343
    2019-08-21 10:40:25.343 NULL
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results so it is clear what *you* mean by "between the range".  Do you want *any* overlap?  *Complete* overlap?  Are the ends included?  Also, no SQL statement begins with `BETWEEN`, so I would expect that snippet to generate an error.  My guess is that it is in a larger query, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Proper date and `NULL` logic. The above doesn't really fill in the full picture, but this should show you what to do:

```
WHERE DateColumn >= '20190101'
  AND (DateColumn < '20191024'
   OR  DateColumn IS NULL)
```

This'll return all rows where `DateColumn` is on or after 01 January 2019 and is **before** but not including 24 October 2019 or `NULL`.

I personally prefer the `>=` AND `<` method as dates can include times. A value like `2019-10-23T00:00:00.003` is not `<= '20191023'` (it's 3 milliseconds later). Like wise, if you were to use `20191024` as the upper boundary and you use `<=` then you could end up with undesired rows that occur at exactly `2019-10-24T00:00:00.000`.

---

Based on the OPs sample data, it actually seems they want a logic reversal:

```
WHERE DateColumn <= '20191024'
  AND (DateColumn > '20190101'
   OR  DateColumn IS NULL)
```

This'll return any row that was "active" between on any date between 01 January 2019 and 23 October 2019 inclusive.

Comment: Would I need to set the DateColumn that is null to the current date?

Comment: No, @Jefferson, this handles `NULL` values. "Setting" the value of `DateColumn` would require an `UPDATE` statement, which is going to ruin your data.

Comment: Thanks @larnu updated the question with a sample of the data can you look again.

Comment: So, in the above, it would be `StartDate >= ...` and then `(EndDate < ... EndDate IS NULL)`

Comment: if the date is 2019-08-22 should I see the the one row with the null enddate? I am not returning any data.

Comment: Well that depends, is the Start Date on or after? The only row with `NULL` for `EndDate` has a value of `2019-08-21T10:40:25.343` for `StartDate`, which isn't on or after `20190822`.

Comment: Perhaps you're after the later logic, @Jefferson . Without expected results for that sample data (that isn't a single row) difficult to do more than guess

Comment: The 22 is after the 21 and the enddate is null

Comment: Correct, why i think you're actually after the new logic I've added.

Comment: Sorry one last question if I set the date at 2019-08-21 should I get three row?

Comment: Why not try and find out, @Jefferson?

Comment: just get the one I was thinking it should be three

Comment: I am out of guesses at this stage, @Jefferson. Like I said, we need those expected results.

Answer (score 2):

If you do want to use the BETWEEN, try doing the ISNULL or COALESCE inside the CAST.
Assuming that EndDate is a datetime field.

```
 AND '2019-08-22' BETWEEN CAST(Version.StartDate AS DATE) AND CAST(COALESCE(Version.EndDate, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```

Comment: The problem i have with this, is it makes any index on the table useless; `COALESCE` isn't a SARGable function.

Comment: @Larnu That's a good point. If there are indexes on the StartDate and/or EndDate then because of functions like CAST then the optimizer would ignore to make use them.  But that's only if there are actually indexes on those fields.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you most likely want is something along these lines:

```
WHERE '2019-08-22' >= StartDate AND ('2019-08-22' <= EndDate OR EndDate IS NULL)
```

The above condition would return true for any input date bounded below by `StartDate` and above by `EndDate` *or* if `EndDate` be missing (i.e. `NULL`), that would also satisfy the criteria.

Comment: so I can't use the between?

Comment: @Jefferson In principle you _can_ use `BETWEEN`, but the problem is that upper bound needs a `NULL` check on the end date.  By breaking up the range into two terms, it lets us write the logic we need here.